# What objects in V8 I can use in my node.js http app?

Tags: node.js, v8

I was looking around for an inherit way to parse/stringify json in node.js and found that I can use the global V8 exposed object "JSON (so JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify()".  Now, I am wondering what other V8 exposed object I can use in my node.js application.  I searched the web and one instance was referring to the V8 specification.  However, I am not at a level that I can read and decipher what can be reused from the V8 spec in a node.js app.  Can anyone with a deeper knowledge on V8/node.js help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js supports all of the standard JavaScript global objects as defined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects).

Comment: I see. so JSON object is in fact part of JavaScript which is implemented in V8. Thanks!